# Selected segment of UISegmentedControl

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults, uisegmentedcontrol, segment

I am using an UISegmentedControl with two sections: the first is Don't Remember Password and the second is Remember Password. If they select Remember Password, I use NSUserDefaults to remember this. On startup, how do I make Remember Password selected if NSUserDefaults is YES?

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"Remember password"] == YES)
{

    //Make the second segment (segment 1 as it would be called, since first is segment 0) selected
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is as simple as setting selectedSegmentIndex inside of viewDidLoad to ensure that the segment is not nil.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Remember Password"])
    {
        segment.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        segment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Also why not use a `UISwitch` and set the `on` value directly to the stored value?

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! And the reason I'm not using a UISwitch is because it has the values YES and NO and I unless I missed it in the XIB file, don't you have to build a custom switch in order to change the words? Anyway, I used an UISegmentedControl because I though it was easier (AN UI or A UI??). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ya which one is it, I was going based the sound an En-es-string vs a You-eye-view .. which is it.. Edit: it is "a" found the answer here http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/591/1/

Comment: @Joe: You dont have to create a custom switch to get YES and NO, a bool is simple a 1 or 0, check my updated answer to get help with this as a switch will be much easier for your users.

Comment: @Zebs: I am sure Jack is referring to the UI display switch being limited to saying ON and OFF

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with a boolean setting I would recommend using a UISwitch instead of a segmented control. The switch would either activate or de-activate the remember password.

The way you set the value is correct, to get the value back you use:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Remember password"];
```

So if you use a UISwitch you could do:

```
switch.on = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Remember password"];
```

If you do want to use a UISegmentedControl it is a bit longer but just as simple:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Remember password"]) {
        segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
    }
    else{
        segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    }
```

Just remember that a UISwitch makes more senese to the user when dealing with a boolean setting.

**Update:**

To set the value using a switch you simply do:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:switch.on forKey:@"Remember password"];
```

It is a lot simpler than using a UISegmentedControl.